# JMeter extracting multiple dynamic values

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter and below is the response body. I am trying to extract ONLY numbers from below response -

```
<option value="1111">Division One</option>
<option value="2222">Division Two</option>
<option value="3333">Division Three</option>
```

So, my output should be 1111,2222,3333

Thanks,
Rohan

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular expression extractor

And use the regex like the below

option value="[^ ]+"

Or you can use boundary based extractor as well